# multithreading for loop not working in Python with no errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have put together the below and wanted to test multithreading.

I am trying to make the for loop run threaded, so several URLs in the list can be processed in parallel.

This script doesn't error, but it doesn't do anything and I am not sure why.

If I remove the multithreading pieces, it works fine

Can anyone help me?

```
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp 
import requests
import pandas as pd
import datetime

urls = [
  'http://google.co.uk',
  'http://bbc.co.uk/'
]

def do_print(s):
    check_data = pd.DataFrame([])

    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
    except:
        response = 'null'

    try:
        response_code = response.status_code
    except:
        response_code = 'null'

    try:
        response_content = response.content
    except:
        response_content = 'null'

    try:        
        response_text = response.text
    except:
        response_text = 'null'

    try:
        response_content_type = response.headers['Content-Type']
    except:
        response_content_type = 'null'

    try:
        response_server = response.headers['Server']
    except:
        response_server = 'null'

    try:
        response_last_modified = response.headers['Last-Modified']
    except:
        response_last_modified = 'null'

    try:
        response_content_encoding = response.headers['Content-Encoding']
    except:
        response_content_encoding = 'null'

    try:
        response_content_length = response.headers['Content-Length']
    except:
        response_content_length = 'null'    

    try:
        response_url = response.url
    except:
        response_url = 'null'

    if int(response_code) <400:
        availability = 'OK'
    elif int(response_code) >399 and int(response_code) < 500:
        availability = 'Client Error'
    elif int(response_code) >499:
        availability = 'Server Error'

    if int(response_code) <400:
        availability_score = 1
    elif int(response_code) >399 and int(response_code) < 500:
        availability_score = 0
    elif int(response_code) >499:
        availability_score = 0

    d = {'check_time': [now], 'code': [response_code], 'type': [response_content_type], 'url': [response_url], 'server': [response_server], 'modified': [response_last_modified], 'encoding': [response_content_encoding], 'availability': [availability], 'availability_score': [availability_score]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    check_data = check_data.append(df ,ignore_index=True,sort=False)

if __name__=="__main__":
    p=mp.Pool(4)
    p.map(do_print, urls) 
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: your mind mistake is that you use `try/except` but you never display error message - so you may have error but you don't know it. And error message would explain you what is the problem. You should at least do `except Exception as ex: print(ex)`

Comment: you should use `return check_data` in `do_print()` and get results  `results = p.map(...)`

Comment: when I run code then I get error because it try to convert `int("null")` - all because you have `except: response_code = 'null'`. If I use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` then I get error that variable `url` doesn't exists. And it is try because you have `def do_print(s):` but it should be `def do_print(url):`

Comment: Instead of all the try-excepts, you can write `response_code = getattr(response, "status_code", "null")`. The syntax of `getattr` is `getattr(object, attribute_of_object, value_if_doesnt_exist)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run code I get error because it try to convert `int("null")` - all because you have

```
except: 
    response_code = 'null'`
```

If I use `except Exception as ex: print(ex)` then I get error that variable `url` doesn't exists. And it is true because you have `def do_print(s):` but it should be `def do_print(url):`

BTW: instead of `'null'` you could use standard `None` and later check `if response_code:`  before you try to covnert it to integer. Or simply skip rest of code when you get error.

---

Other problem - process should use `return df` and you should get it

```
results = p.map(...)
```

and then use `results` to create DataFrame `check_data`

Comment: Thanks so much for your help - I was being stupid :)